# WeChat InApp payment screen shows up only for first time

Tags: android, payment, wechat

I'm trying to implement **WeChat InApp payments** in our app. But we are struggling to make it work.

I will try to sum it up real quick.

1. Given user is **not** logged in, WeChat login screen show up every time.
2. Given user **is** logged in, when clicked on pay button for a **first** time, WeChat order info screen shows up, but when clicked **back**, and clicked on pay button **again** (in our app), WeChat screen **doesn’t** show up.

We did implemented `WXPayEntryActivity` but neither `onCreate`, `onNewIntent` nor `onResp` are called. And yes, this activity is sending broadcast but neither toast nor log shows up.

I tried call `registerApp` on application  started, I tried it just before creating payment req.

Did anybody come across this issue?

Can WeChat help me directly?

---

Want to see some code?

This is my payment class

```
public class WXInAppPayment {

    public void startPayment(AppCompatActivity activity, PaymentDataResponse data) {
        IWXAPI api = getApi(activity);
        if (api.isWXAppInstalled()) {
            api.sendReq(getPayRequest(data));
        } else {
            // Showing toast
        }
    }

    public WXReceiver getReceiver() {
        // returning BR for wechat payments
        return new WXReceiver();
    }

    public IntentFilter getIntentFilter() {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Constants.WE_CHAT_BR_ID);
        return intentFilter;
    }

    private IWXAPI getApi(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        final IWXAPI api = WXAPIFactory.createWXAPI(activity, null);
        api.registerApp(Constants.WE_CHAT_APP_ID);
        return api;
    }

    private PayReq getPayRequest(PaymentDataResponse data) {
        PayReq request = new PayReq();
        request.appId = dataFromAPI.appId;
        request.partnerId = dataFromAPI.partnerId;
        request.prepayId = dataFromAPI.prepayId;
        request.packageValue = dataFromAPI.packageValue;
        request.nonceStr = dataFromAPI.nonceStr;
        request.timeStamp = dataFromAPI.timestimeStampamp;
        request.sign = dataFromAPI.sign;
        return request;
    }
}
```

And this is WXPayEntryActivity. In manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".wxapi.WXPayEntryActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:exported="true"/>
```

And class:

```
public class WXPayEntryActivity extends Activity implements IWXAPIEventHandler {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private IWXAPI api;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        api = WXAPIFactory.createWXAPI(this, Constants.WE_CHAT_APP_ID);
        api.handleIntent(getIntent(), this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        api.handleIntent(intent, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReq(BaseReq baseReq) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onReq: " + baseReq.transaction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResp(BaseResp baseResp) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onResp: " + baseResp.errStr + " " + baseResp.errCode);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.WE_CHAT_BR_ID);
        intent.putExtra("error_code", baseResp.errCode);
        intent.putExtra("error_string", baseResp.errStr);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through same issue... Your code look fine.
lets cover the scenario:

- This is normal ... if user is not logged in.. Wechat App will
  redirect to login screen
- "Only first time payment passed" happened due to wrong packageName. consider these checks:
- You need to use ApplicationId not packageName
- WhiteSpace
- Debug buildType by default has suffix: `.debug` to applicatonId
- Check AppSign which is MD5 of cert you sign with.. Be careful not to use the default one for debug buildType.
- Try to reassign ApplicationId and AppSign it again.(that was our issue ) due to hidden WS not visible.
- Contact Wechat team support.. they have logs to payment.